# Python query ElasticSearch path with backslash

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, elasticsearch-py

I'm using the Elastic search extension to Python, trying to query specific path.

Here is my wrapped query:

```
{
"size": 1000,
 "query": {
   "filtered": {
     "filter": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "term": {
               "Path": "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Which works fine in **kopf** plugin.

Here is my Python code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=['my_server'])
index = "my_index"
query = '{"size":1000,"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"Path":"c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"}}]}}}}}'
response = es.search(index=index, body=query)
```

For some reason I'm getting this error (which will not occur without the backslash):

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py",
>   line 69, in _wrapped
>       return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py",
>   line 530, in search
>       doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py",
>   line 329, in perform_request
>       status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py",
>   line 106, in perform_request
>       self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py",
>   line 105, in _raise_error
>       raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError

This problem happens only when there are backslashes.

Note: I'm working on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "Path" to `c:\\\\myfolder\\\\myfile.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it didn't occurred to me :)